# Accessibility Label for composite view

Tags: ios, accessibility

I have a custom `UIView` that combines a few different views. How do I specify the accessibility label and/or value at the superview level, and remove accessibility from the component parts? VoiceOver is describing the subviews when their values are misleading in the context of the overall view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your `UIView` that has to be accessible, set the `accessibilityElementsHidden` property to YES;

See the [`accessibilityElementsHidden` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAccessibility_Protocol/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSObject/accessibilityElementsHidden).

Comment: Duh - missed that. Thanks Nitin. A follow up - how would you define a state-dependednt accessibility label dynamically for the group, given that the group is not a UIView subclass of its own (it is built in another view)? I think I might have to move it to a discrete UIView subclass. Great CocoaHeads presentation by the way!

Comment: (Or I can just update the accessibility state at the same time as the visual state I guess).

Comment: Thanks Ben! if I understand your followup question correctly, you should be able to update the label as many times as you want by setting the accessibilityLabel property (as often) on the instance of the composite UIView.